# why is <frame> element scroll height equal to frame height

Tags: javascript

I have a `<frame>` element where source contents need to scroll. The standard scrollbars appear and works as expected. However, if I add attribute **scrolling="no"** to frame element I expected the frame scroll height to be larger than the frame height. It's actually equal. Why?

I'd like to be able to manually scroll content if possible using frame `scrollTop` and frame `scrollHeight`.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because those properties only matter for scrollable `<div>`s etc. when using the `overflow` CSS attributes. The `<frame>` element isn't scrollable in those terms, just its contents are, if that makes sense.

Comment: assuming that by frame you're referring to an iframe. if you set the scrolling="no" you are basically telling it to disable scrolling. try changing the scrolling height or width. scrolling should be set to TRUE. because scrolling is disabled it will be =, because it is now disabled. hope this helps